# Implement Basic strategy authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I it possible to implement basic strategy authentication in my API with Azure AD B2C?
I explored internet but there is no doc for this policy.
The scenario that I will to implement is:

There are an API that I want to protected with Azure AD B2C.
Customers can call the APIs with provided user&pass and get their data

Comment: Hi, @Navid Ahrary If one of the answers solves your problem, you can accept it to end the thread.  ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of B2C is that users aren't sharing passwords with your API. Instead, they go to B2C (interactive or non-interactive way) and get a token. Using this token they call your API and your API validates this token. However, if you still thinks that this is the one and only way to build your app, what you can do is that from the backend you can request a token for your users using a policy for "Sign in using resource owner password credentials (ROPC)".

For make this work, you have to set up B2C, create this policy and then using it with code similar to this (C#):

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ropc/oauth2/v2.0/token");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
request.AddParameter("username", "YOUR_USERNAME");
request.AddParameter("password", "YOUR_PASSWORD");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
request.AddParameter("scope", "openid offline_access https://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/your_app_name/user_impersonation");
request.AddParameter("client_id", "YOUR_CLIENT_ID");
request.AddParameter("response_type", "token id_token");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

where B2C_1_ropc is your created policy name

Answer (score 0):

The idea provided by @Georgy Grigoryev is correct, but a more detailed operation process needs to be added:

According to your question:  you want to expose the api protected by Azure, and then log in to the user and call the api to get their data.

You need to create 2 applications in the Azure AD B2C portal, one representing the client application and the other representing the api application, then use the user to log in to the client application, and use the client application to access the api application.

First, you need to expose the api of the back-end application:

[image]

Next, add the scope exposed by the api application to the client application (you can find your exposed api permissions in **My APIs**), so that the client can access the api, and then grant the **admin consent** for the permission.

[image]

Finally, you need to create a [resource owner user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) and log in users to obtain access tokens.

[image]